# Modify an Android tablet to run only one application

Tags: android

I would like to modify an Android tablet (for instance a Nexus 7) in order to run only 1 application on the device. The user should not be able to leave the application or see the home/settings android menu.

When the tablet starts, the application is launched straight away and no other applications should be startable.

How is it possible to have this behavior?

Comment: If anyone is interested, this app does this pretty well: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

The only way to block the user from using any other aspect of the tablet is to make your app the launcher.

By doing so, it will be displayed whenever the tablet is unlocked, and the home button will just take the user to your app. If you don't launch any other app from yours, you will effectively lock the user into your app on the device.